# Catch exceptions in subclasses __init__ and exit

Tags: python, exception

Consider the code below:

```
class Parent():
    
    def __init__(self, ...):
        # set up logging
        # ....


class Child(Parent):
    
    def __init__(self, ...):
        super(Child, self).__init__(...)

        print(1/0)


c = Child()
```

The above will fail because of the `1/0`. Is it possible to have some logic (ex: I want to log something) in the `Parent` execute when the `__init__` fails? That is, I'd like to catch exceptions in the `Child` class's `__init__` *and then do things like logging* prior to the entire instance be garbage collected.

Comment: After the `super()` call returns, the `Child` class's constructor is completely independent from that of the parent. You would not be able to catch an error in the `Child` class's constructor as the parent constructor function has already been called (with `super(...)`) and returned, and so it is no longer in the call stack. An error in the child constructor will be thrown to the caller, which is the code that initializes an instance of the `Child` class (in this case the top-level).

Comment: It's not the parent's job to clean up after the child.

Comment: The `Child`'s `__init__()` could catch exceptions and call a method of its `Parent` to handle it.

Comment: You may also be looking for the [Factory Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), in which your factory method would be able to handle thrown errors while initializing an instance.

Answer (score 2):

You have to make the execution of the offending code something that the parent actually runs. One way to do this is to define the code not in `__init__` itself, but in a hook executed by the parent. (The `dataclasses` module does something similar.)

```
class Parent():
    
    def __init__(self, ...):
        # set up logging
        # ....
        
        try:
            self.post_init()
        except Exception:
            ...

    # Do-nothing implementation in case the child doesn't override it
    def post_init(self):
        pass

class Child(Parent):
    
    def post_init(self):
        print(1/0)
    

c = Child()
```

Comment: I definitely don't agree with your claim the making the offending code something that the parent executes is a strict requirement. In fact, I think what you've proposed is might even be an anti-pattern.

Comment: This is just an example of the same kind of code numerous frameworks empty. The child decides *what* code gets run, but the parent decides when and how. This is a nearly verbatim copy of the `__post_init__` method provided by the `dataclass` decorator.

Comment: OK, insinuating it might be an anti-pattern was too severe, I can see how it could be useful in the context of some larger framework — sorry — but I still stand by my assertion that it is not any kind of strict requirement nor something you *have* to do.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be by decorating each subclass' `__init__()` method with something that would handle any exceptions that occur. You *could* do that explicitly in each subclass or automatically by defining a metaclass **or** by using the relatively new [`__init_subclass__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init_subclass__) method which was added in Python 3.6.

That latter seems like the simplest way to make it automatic, so I'll illustrate doing it that way:

```
from functools import wraps

class Parent:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # set up logging...
        pass

    def logger(self, msg):
        print('logging msg:', msg)

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
        cls.__init__ = cls.log_exceptions(cls.__init__)  # Decorate subclass' __init__.

    @staticmethod
    def log_exceptions(method):
        """ Wrap method in an exception handler that will automatically log any
            exceptions that occur executing it.
        """
        @wraps(method)
        def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
            try:
                return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as exc:
                self.logger(exc)
        return wrapped


class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"{type(self).__name__}.__init__() called")
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)  # Base class initialization.
        # other initializations...
        print(1 / 0)


c = Child(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this could be defining a logger method in your parent, so that every methods in child classes (including `__init__`) can get to it by inheriting `logger` method.

```
class Parent:

    def __init__(self, *args):
        print(args, 'Parent')

    def logger(self, msg):
        print('logging', msg)


class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)

        # other initializations here

        # the code may cause problem
        try:
            print(1 / 0)
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger(e)


c = Child(1, 2, 3)
```

output :

```
(1, 2, 3) Parent
logging division by zero
```

Every `child` classes can also override `logger` method and add something specific in addition to parent's `logger` if they want.